# Load Database - how to show progress in progressBar?

Tags: android, database, progress-bar

I'm trying to use a ProgressBar, which shows the progress of loading a database, which is in the local assets folder. I don't know if it's even possible this way, because I'm using code which was before for downloading a file from the internet.

I think that I would have to get the size of the database, but I have no idea how to do this. The conection.getContentLength() doesn't seem to work. May the conection doesn't contain the address assets/kneipen2.sqlite ?

This is in the onCreate():

```
new LoadFilesTask().execute("assets/kneipen2.sqlite");
```

And this is the AsyncTask inner class:

```
private class LoadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

     @Override
     protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls) {      

         //oeffneDatenbank();
         int count;
         try {

             myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(Start.this);       
            try {           
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();            
            } 
             catch (IOException ioe) {          
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");
            }
            try {

                myDbHelper.openDataBase();

            } catch (SQLException sqle) {

                throw sqle;
            }       

             URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

             //Ignore this! Only used to show that operations can take a long time to complete...
             URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
             conection.connect();
             int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
             // downlod File
             InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
             byte data[] = new byte[1024];

             long total = 0;
             while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                 total += count;
                 // publishing the progress....
                 publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));       
             }
             input.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {}
         return null;            
    }
```

So, there isn't shown a progress, but at the end the database is loaded correctly. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in two ways :
Either 
preExecute() and postExecute() method of AsyncTask where in preExecute() just show thr progressDialog and in postExecute() dismiss the same.
or
Use Handler to show progress dialog and dismiss the same...

Hope u get what i say...

Comment: Yes, I got what you said, thanks. And it works very well. So, this solution is a good one, and it works, but finally, if it's possible, I would for reasons of the layout, still like to let the progressBar show the progress of loading the local file. Is that possible? If not, is there a way to take influence on the appearance of the progressDialog?

Answer (score 2):

```
ProgressDialog MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show( YourCurrentClass.this, "Please wait!" , "Loading..", true);
```

This might be of help

Comment: Yes, this helps, thanks. But so you mean that there isn't a way to let the ProgressBar show the progress of loading a locale file? Because the ProgressDialog is a good solution, but the progressBar would be a better for me, the reason is the design/layout.

Comment: I think [ProgressBar]<http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html> is what you are looking for